# MySQL statement to get min value with max ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the minimum value with the largest id.  For example, I want to select Playstation because it has a larger id than Silly Puddy.

This is my sql statement:

```
SELECT *, max(id), min(price)
FROM table
group by type
ORDER BY id DESC 


id      name                    type        price
123451  Park's Great Hits       Music       19.99
123452  Silly Puddy             Toy         3.99
123453  Playstation             Toy         3.99
```

I keep getting Silly Puddy returned for Toy.  Any suggestions on what to do differently?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have been confused. Since `id` is unique, You always find only a value, Of course, this is "min value", this is also "max value".

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as soon as id unique - there is only one price for one id, no any "minimum" or "maximum", just one:

```
select * from table where id in (
SELECT max(id)
FROM table as a
where a.price = (select min(price) from table as b where a.type=b.type)
group by type
) as t
```

Comment: I understand the requirement to be _the greatest `id` among the group having the lowest `price`_. This is the greatest `id` overall.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski here you go

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. This should do it.

```
select t4.* 

from 

`table` t4 

join 

( 

    select t2.type, max(t2.id) as id 
    from 
    `table` t2 join 
    (
        select type, min(price) as price
        from
        `table` t1
        group by type
    ) t3 on t2.type = t3.type and t2.price = t3.price
    group by t2.type

)  t5 on t4.id = t5.id
```